# How can I change the english captions in pander?

Tags: knitr, pandoc, pander

I am using pander to print nicer looking tables via RStudio, knitr, pander, pandoc, Word.
I have a two-page table, to which I would like to add a Spanish caption:

```
set.caption("Límites izquierdo y derecho para las diferentes variables")
pander(LimitesUnivariado, include.rownames=FALSE)
```

This almost works, but my caption states:

```
Table: Límites izquierdo y derecho para las diferentes variables (continued below)
```

I can't find find the way to change the `Table` and `continued below` to their Spanish equivalents. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/helpers.R) it seems that those are hard-coded in.  The package author @daroczig frequents SO though so he'll probably see this at some point.  You might want to submit an issue [here](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues) though.

Comment: @dason I've submitted the issue, thank you!

Comment: Thanks @ap53 for the question, I will definitely add a new option in `pander` package to update the `continued below` hardcoded string to anything in the next few days (hopefully in 24 hours) - although not sure about letting users update the `Table:` prefix as that is part of Pandoc syntax: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables
PS: I have added the `pander` tag to the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for [reporting this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/issues/28), I have just pushed a few lines to the `master` branch which introduced two new options to tweak the caption if the table was split. Quick example:

1. Update the default caption of split tables without specified captions:

   ```
   > panderOptions('table.continues', 'Continuará')
   > pander(mtcars)
   ```
2. Update affix concatenated to user specified caption if the table was split:

   ```
   > panderOptions('table.continues.affix', '(continuará)')
   > set.caption('MTCARS')
   > pander(mtcars)
   ```

Please [install the most recent version of `pander`](http://rapporter.github.com/pander/#installation) and verify if this update would work for you - and sorry for the above lame examples, please note that unfortunately I do not speak Spanish.

PS: I have not touched the `Table:` prefix as that seems to be specified in Pandoc's syntax which is to be removed by Pandoc automatically anyway when the conversion to some other document format is being done: please see the [relevant docs](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#tables). But if you would find a new options about this latter too, I would happily add that to the package in a jiffy.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the quick answer.  I can live with the Table issue ;-)

Comment: The `relevant docs` state:  

```
    A caption is a paragraph beginning with the string Table: (or just :), which will be stripped off.  
```
  
Do you think an option to just use ':' would work?

Comment: Sure, please check the new `table.caption.prefix` option, @ap53: https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/commit/0eb5e9af9ce8744c937caeef3060596b99cf3179

Comment: It works as well. Initially I thought I needed to use ':' as prefix, but pandoc didn't strip it in the docx. So I tried a spanish 'Tabla: ' and it came out great. Thanks again!